# g++ regex crash on (possibly unsyntactic) expression

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, crash, g++4.8

I figure the following program should either complain it can't compile the regular expression or else treat it as legal and compile it fine (I don't have the standard so I can't say for sure whether the expression is strictly legal; certainly reasonable interpretations are possible). Anyway, what happens with `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1` is that, when run, it crashes hard

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08b51248 ***
```

in the guts of the library.

Questions are:

a) it's bug, right? I assume (perhaps incorrectly) the standard doesn't say std::regex can crash if it doesn't like the syntax. (msvc eats it fine, fwiw)

b) if it's a bug, is there some easy way to see whether it's been reported or not (my first time poking around gnu-land bug systems was intimidating)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(void)
    {
    const char* Pattern = "^(%%)|";
    std::regex Machine;

    try {
        Machine = Pattern;
        }
    catch(std::regex_error e)
        {
        std::cerr << "regex could not compile pattern: "
          << Pattern << "\n"
          << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'd say that you've got a bug in the regex parser, since what it should do is to match anything. The pipe character instructs the regex parser to match the expressions on either side of it. Since in your case the right hand side is empty it should match anything. I guess you're after to match a pipe charachter, and thus should escape it and it should work.

Comment: Btw, is that regex just a test, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: `<regex>` was non-functional in gcc-4.8.1's libstdc++. If you can use LLVM's libc++, use that, [your program works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e061305dca0676ba) . Otherwise - boost.regex

Comment: @ClasG in olden days (not so long after Ken Thompson's wonderful algorithm was published), `|` with an empty argument was used to match epsilon (zero characters), effectively providing a `?` operator without having to reserve another special character. This bug emerged from code that programmatically generates a regex-based lexical analyzer from a table of patterns/toktypes. I was modifying it to binary search for *another* regex bug, and incorrectly ended up with a `|` on the end.

Comment: @Cubbi Thank you! I was about to retort that 4.8.1 claims regex support but I see that I was off by 0.0.1 versions! OK, now I just have to figure how to get a system with 4.8.2 functioning. Part of the point of this project is to explore how ready for prime time C++ 11 support is in two major compilers (a bit less than Bjarne imagines, when it comes to regex), so I'm not interested in alternative libs but what can be done with vanilla C++ 11.

Comment: @RonBurk Core language support is good in gcc, but their standard library has a long way to go. Incidentally, my coliru link above did not use alternative libs.

Comment: @Cubbi Your comment made me give clang a try. Unfortunately, getting everything for it installed correctly turned out to be beyond me, and I gave up after a few tries. Not sure why it has to be so much harder than apt-get install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put this in a comment, but I can't, so...

I don't know if you already know, but it seems to be the pipe | character at the end that's causing your problems. It seems like the character representation of |  as a last character (since "^(%%)|a" works fine for me) given by g++ is making a mess when regex tries to call free();

The standard (or at least the online draft I'm reading) claims that:

```
28.8
Class template basic_regex
[re.regex]

1 For a char-like type charT, specializations of class template basic_regex represent regular expressions
constructed from character sequences of charT characters. In the rest of 28.8, charT denotes a given char-
like type. Storage for a regular expression is allocated and freed as necessary by the member functions of
class basic_regex.

2 Objects of type specialization of basic_regex are responsible for converting the sequence of charT objects
to an internal representation. It is not specified what form this representation takes, nor how it is accessed by
algorithms that operate on regular expressions.
[ Note: Implementations will typically declare some function
templates as friends of basic_regex to achieve this — end note ]
```

and later,

```
basic_regex& operator=(const charT* ptr);

3 Requires: ptr shall not be a null pointer.

4 Effects: returns assign(ptr).
```

So unless g++ thinks const char* Pattern ="|"; is a null ptr (I would imagine not...),
I guess it's a bug?

EDIT: Incidentally, consecutive || (even when not at the end) seem to cause a segmentation fault for me also.

Comment: That's probably as good an answer as I'll get; it at least bolsters my confidence that a regex syntax error is not classified as "undefined behavior".

Comment: So I also can't comment on other people's comments, but regarding your comment to @Cubbi, I just yesterday fought my way through installing gcc-4.8.2 on a cluster to my $HOME/gcc directory without root access, so maybe I can help if you're still looking to do that?